# OSError: Unable to open file (can't retrieve stat info for file)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, hdf5

I am training a neural network in Keras on a dataset of MRI files in hdf5 format. After running few steps of an epoch successfully, suddenly the above error comes up.

```
File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 88, in h5py.h5f.open

OSError: Unable to open file (can't retrieve stat info for file)
```

I am running my code on Google Colab, and one observation is that it does not come while using a CPU and the execution speed is slow, it occurs when GPU is being used and execution is faster.
Could anyone please suggest how to debug it?
Following is the last statement of the error -

```
HDF5: infinite loop closing library
  L,T_top,P,P,Z,FD,E,SL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL,FL
```

Comment: Found the similar issue resolved [here](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/hdf5-infinite-loop-closing-library-v1-10-6/8468), which might help you to fix this error.